# Bootstrap Grid - Images not aligning at different breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I've a client who wants three images to sit in a simple layout which is working perfectly on mobile:

http://www.boutiquebeautyaberdeen.com/img/mobile.png

On a desktop size they are a few pixels out.

http://www.boutiquebeautyaberdeen.com/img/desktop.png

(Stack Overflow wont let me just post the images yet)

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="img-responsive"><br>
           <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6">
           <img src="http://placehold.it/300x425" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>
```

- I got to the height of the image (425) by trial and error.

Is this just my lack of understanding of the bootstrap grid system? 
Or should I be using something like flexbox to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to rounding errors. Because your columns are not 300 pixels wide, the images are scaled down. This is done pixel-wise for the width of the image, the height adapts depending on the aspect ratio of the image. So if you have images with different aspect ratios, it is not guaranteed the scaled versions will end up with a matching height.

**Example**

An image with aspect ratio 1:3 will scale 3 pixels in height for each pixel in width.

An image width aspect ratio 1:2 will scale only 2 pixels in height for each pixel in width.

So changing the width of the columns by one pixel will make the resulting heights differ, if they were aligned before.

You can not do much about this, if your layout is fluid. If it is static, you can for example adapt the column widths to values that make a match for the given aspect ratios. Another option might be to adapt the margin between the images on the left in order to add the missing pixel(s).

Comment: Thank you - I'm wondering if its normal practice (when using bootstraps default grid) to size the images accordingly. I assumed it was better to "let bootstrap sort the sizes out". Maybe not.

Comment: Bootstrap can't really do much about this problem, it's just a mathematical thing. The browser would sometimes need to draw half pixels and it doesn't do that for images. So heights are rounded and that yields the difference.

Comment: There is actually one more point regarding your mobile layout that makes it even more difficult: the vertical margin between the two images in the left won't scale with the column width. So in a fluid layout it would break even if the images were sized correctly.

Comment: Fixed height layouts should be avoided because of stuff like that. They quickly get you into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a matter of math rounding. Since the images are scaled for mobile, partial pixel values must be rendered as whole pixels.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/ut4w64q8

```
required code that's not really code
```

Comment: Thank isherwood. Mind if I ask about the code comment? I'm still new here.

Comment: SO requires that code be included with links to JSFiddle, and rightly so. In this case, the link was merely a demo of your original code, so there was no new code to post.

Comment: Ah-ha! Makes sense... there's a more to SO than meets the eye - thanks again